# Symfony 3 unique constraint in form with non mapped field

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3 and I'm working on a form without a mapped entity, with `data_class => null` like :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname', null, ['label' => 'user.edit.label.firstname'])
            ->add('lastname', null, ['label' => 'user.edit.label.lastname'])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, ['label' => 'common.email', ])
            ->add('state', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'common.state',
                'choices' => array_flip(CompanyHasUser::getConstants())
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null,
            'translation_domain' => 'messages'
        ));
    }
```

So with this, how can I constraint my field `'email'` to be unique ? I need to check that in my entity User (attribute=email).

Any ideas ?

Comment: What's you Symfony version?

Comment: Symfony 3.3 !!!!

Comment: Sadly the `UniqueEntity` can work with entity only (even by using a DTO doesn't work).  Try with `Callback` constraint.

Comment: @JakubMatczak even though you can pass an `entityClass` the related object _must_ be managed by the entity manager

Comment: Also, you can set `unique=true` the email property of the `User` entity and catch the `UniqueConstraintViolationException` on flush and add the form error manually to this email form field.

Comment: Or... configure `UniqueEntity` into User class and after setting it with this form, call to `$error = $validator->validate($user)` and get the errors

Answer (score 1):

Without a mapped entity, you'll have to check against the database. Easiest way to do that is to inject the UserRepository to your form class. ([Inject a repository link](https://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2014/05/inject-a-repository-instead-of-an-entity-manager/).)

In your repository, create a method to query that ensures an email doesn't already exist. This could pretty easily return a boolean true or false.

In your form, create a custom constraint callback.

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'         => null,
            'translation_domain' => 'messages',
            'constraints'        => [
                new Callback([
                    'callback' => [$this, 'checkEmails'],
                ]),
            ]))
        ;
    }
```

And add the callback function in the same form class, using the UserRepo.

```
/**
 * @param $data
 * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
 */
public function checkEmails($data, ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    $email = $data['email'];
    if ($this->userRepository->checkEmail($email)) {
        $context->addViolation('You are already a user, log in.');
    }
}
```

See also this [blog post on callback constraints without an entity](http://shout.setfive.com/2013/06/27/symfony2-forms-without-an-entity-and-with-a-conditional-validator/).

Comment: I didn't actually test this code. You will have to play around with it.